# Do I need to play video to generate transcription

Tags: java, api, speech-recognition

I'm making a thesis about Speech Recognition for generating subtitle out of the video itself. The concept is I'm planning to make a video player and integrate the Speech Recognition on that. So if I run the system and play the video until it ends, the system will generate another copy of that video file, but this time subtitle is already included or integrated on that. Is this concept possible? If so, can you please advise me on how can I do it, or tell me whats the best SR API or some sort out there? I'm familiar in java btw.

Comment: So, If you are looking for some mentor, who can guide you on your idea( which is real effort btw and needs to be paid instead of getting free cookies). Start here: [https://www.freelancer.com/]

Comment: sorry but i dont have much that money for hiring freelancer :(. but any advice is very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a similar sort of Idea in my mind in my university years.

I think your approach should be work. Play the Movie first time and then generate the subtitle and export it to a *".srt"* file. Because you cant do it in Real-time Processing due to the several reasons like

1. Sentences meanings can be change from words to word
2. Processing or analysing time

etc.

**Disadvantage of your approach is**
People won't like to play the whole movie to generate the subtitle file.

**So I think it would be better** to extract the Sound track (audio file), analyzing the sound track and generate the Subtitle file without Playing the Movie

In here you wont able to do the SPEECH-TO-TEXT conversion.
You have to find the way to analyse the sound waves styles and extract the data.

Good Luck

Comment: Thankyou mate for suggestion. One thing I'm concern is I cant think of any solutions or methods on how can i generate subtitle file just by analyzing only the sound track. :(. I can only think of Speech-To-Text conversion in this.

Comment: Is this a research project?

Comment: Yes sir, for my undergrad degree.